# Ektron 9 moving towards MVC framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ektron

We have many web portals running on ektron 8.5 and would like to confirm if ektron 9 is going to move from web forms to MVC architecture?
I visited their official websites for more info, but no luck.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a direct programming question, and is localized to a specific point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ektron 9 has already been released and remains a web forms application.

As for the future beyond the 9 branch, MVC has been a popular request, but it seems unlikely given the fundamental changes that would need to be made to what is currently an iteratively built system.

Comment: MVC can be supported as part of a 3-Tier architecture (our Synergy conference site is MVC 3-Tier), but the base is still web forms. There are no immediate plans to change that.

Comment: It should also be noted that most (all?) of the Ektron API libraries work just fine in MVC projects - it is just the workarea and pagebuilder that require web forms.

Comment: Framework APIs in MVC. Legacy APIs aren't supported. There's parity for most activities between the two, so it's not typically an issue.